# Vectorise for-loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I need to replace this `for`-loop with better code:

```
for g=1:length(B)
    C(g,:)=[A(B(g,1),:),A(B(g,2),:),A(B(g,3),:)];
end
```

where:

- `A` is an *N<sub>a</sub>*-by-*2* matrix,
- `B` is an *N<sub>b</sub>*-by-*3* matrix and
- `C` is an *N<sub>b</sub>*-by-*6* matrix.

The `for`-loop is working, but is too slow.

example of matrix:

```
A =

 1     2
 1     3
 1     4
 1     5
 1     6
 2     3
 2     4
 2     5
 2     6

B =

 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     2     6
 1     2     7
 1     2     8
 1     2     9

C =

 1     2     1     3     1     4
 1     2     1     3     1     5
 1     2     1     3     1     6
 1     2     1     3     2     3
 1     2     1     3     2     4
 1     2     1     3     2     5
 1     2     1     3     2     6
```

Comment: `C = [A(B(:,1),:),A(B(:,2),:),A(B(:,3),:)]`?

Comment: What kind of performance characteristics are you looking for?

Comment: @AnthonyMichaelCook if length(B) is high for-loop is too slow

Comment: Could you post an example for `A`, `B`, `C` that we can test on?

Comment: @CST-Link i've added the examples

Comment: @PietroZ. I've added examples too in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    C1 = reshape(A(B.',:).', 6, []).';
```

Test:

```
    %% Build minimal case
    A = reshape(1:10, 5, 2);
    B = randi(size(A,1), 7, 3);

    %% Original code
    for g=1:length(B)
        C(g,:)=[A(B(g,1),:),A(B(g,2),:),A(B(g,3),:)];
    end

    %% Proposed code
    C1 = reshape(A(B.',:).', 6, []).';

    %% Test
    disp(all(C1(:) == C(:)));
```

Comment: @PietroZ. I'd be curious about the speed gain, if you have some timings.